# How can I run a sequence of Animations? AnimationSet is failing me

Tags: java, android, animation, nested-class

I have a custom view `Dial`. This view has a custom animation `DialAnimation` that was written as a nested class of `Dial`. Below is the code from my `Activity` that instantiates `Dial` and attempts to perform a sequence of animations on it. When the code is run, only one of the animations is seen onscreen. What am I missing here?

```
Dial dial = (Dial) findViewById(R.id.dial);
DialAnimation anim1 = dial.new DialAnimation(0, 90, 3000);
DialAnimation anim2 = dial.new DialAnimation(180, 360, 3000);
anim2.setStartOffset(3500);

AnimationSet set = new AnimationSet(false);
set.addAnimation(anim1);
set.addAnimation(anim2);
dial.startAnimation(set);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

one way to do it would be to set an AnimationListener on the first animation and override the onAnimationEnd() to make it start the next animation in the sequence. That would look something like this:

```
animation1Listener = new Animation.AnimationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                 dial.startAnimation(animation2)
            }
}

animation1.setAnimationListener(animation1Listener);
dial.startAnimation(animation1);
```

Answer (score 0):

try animation listner in doinbackground() method this will update your animation in sequence 
..OR u can use simple thread in you application .

Answer (score -1):

Add a .setDuration(3500) method to each animation and ensure that the time for the duration and the time for the .setStartOffset(3500) method for the secondanimation match.